# Filter Textfield Jquery in Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am new to html javascript, jquery any help will be really appreciated I managed to create a table that has filter input but my problem is when I type in search box and i its filtering but when I backspace until the textfield is empty it showing whole rows of the table my pagination didntwork because in my first load without searching yet in the input textfield table showing two rows and has numbers page next button only showing two rows per page but if i filter search and make my field empty it will not limit the rows it will show all rows like right now i have six rows it will shows six rows where I want it to be only two rows shows and when click next two rows  again *link for pagination --> https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Client-side-HTML-Table-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Paging.html   *

**HTML**

```
<table  id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Amount</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>100</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>200</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>300</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Juy</td>
            <td>3000</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>uy</td>
            <td>1000</td>

        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>buy</td>
            <td>10700</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

      $('#myTable').paging({
        limit: 2,
        rowDisplayStyle: 'block',
        activePage: 0,
        rows: []
    });  });
```

Comment: is there anyway i can do it in jquery if field empty toggle two rows?

Comment: since you are using jQuery, you can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It has inbuilt searching, pagination etc.